# What is the relation among connotation, semantics, and pragmatics?

Tags: semantics, pragmatics

I know that connotation meaning belongs to semantic meaning, but what I'm confused about is the connotation meaning is affected by the context, isn't it? If so, why does it not belong to pragmatic meaning?

Comment: Broadly, none at all.

Could you Post some underlying reasoning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The study of meaning is usually divided into two sub-areas, semantics and pragmatics, where semantics is about literal, denotative meaning (looking only at the linguistic form) and pragmatics is about how non-semantic context and semantics interact to generate the broader meaning / communicative function of an utterance. Connotation *is* [considered to be part of pragmatics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S037821660600172X). Confusion might arise over different meanings or definitions of "semantics", and the fact that sometimes literal semantics is called "sentence / word meaning" and pragmatics is called "speaker meaning".

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But why does connotation meaning belong to semantic meanings in many books?  Can we say connotation meaning belongs to both semantics and pragmatics?

Comment: Because those books were not written by linguists. The problem is with the word _meaning_; it has a popular sense of 'whatever one gets out of an utterance', and a technical sense of 'formal logical structure' (excluding "connotation", which has only a popular and not a technical sense). What's called "connotation" in composition (not linguistics) textbooks as a part of "semantics" is just what linguists call "pragmatics". You have to realize that there is far more misinformation available about language than there is real information.

Comment: I can't say that I have ever encountered the term "semantic meaning". If an author only speaks of semantics and not at all of pragmatics, I would suspect that they are using "semantics" as equivalent to "meaning", and didn't get the memo from Austin, Searle and others.

Comment: "Austin, Searle, and others" were precisely not linguists. _Meaning_ and _semantics_ have long histories in philosophy. As Wittgenstein put it,  "_Meaning_ is one of the words of which one may say that they have odd jobs in our  language ... What causes most trouble in philosophy is that   we are tempted to describe the use of important 'odd-job' words as   though they were words with regular functions."

Comment: And yet, linguists have learned a lot about semantics and meaning from reading what the philosophers have to say. A number of semanticists held/hold joint appointments in philosophy.

Comment: Indeed. But linguists don't have to buy the package deal; they tend to pick and choose concepts that fit natural language, like quantifiers and presuppositions, and ignore the handwaving, like "connotation".

Comment: The problem I see here, and in your demarcation, is that *meaning* in general can be viewed from two perspectives. On the one hand, teaching *how to express oneself* primarily has to focus on what is meant. The observer is however not limited to that perspective, and can draw linguistic inference from connotations that the speaker isn't even aware of (I for one at least have frequentlytried to defend myself for *that's* not what I was trying to say, only to become convinced that *it* is what I inadvertently said; e.g. often preceded by "*I don't mean to sound racist, but ...*"). ...

Comment: ... Descriptive linguistics tries to capture all of that, however, each linguist is still limited by their own view point. Semantics can show these limits, while pragmatics should be concerned about how to deal with such limitations and thus has to subsume semantics, which however takes precedence (I say). It might for example be a matter of pragmatics whether to accept a phrase as a single word, or reject that (to avoid the phrase's becoming iconic and dysphemistic) and discourse semantics can be decisive for turning certain connotations overt or rather hide them (e.g. through code).

Comment: I'd say the main reason that "connotation" often occurs in texts about semantics is that the typical linguistics textbook treats semantics first and later goes over pragmatics, and more specifically, the semantics part will often start with lexical semantics, after an introductory part with some discussion of what kinds of questions the fields deal with, how "meaning" can even be defined, etc., in which context the "denotation -- connotation" terminology typically is mentioned first.

Comment: Connotation itself is more of a pragmatic phenomenon, but it will often be mentioned when starting to introduce semantics, to give the reader an overview of the various problems and to discuss which field deals with what.