# What other parts does pragmatics have, besides connotation?

Tags: pragmatics

https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/36533/218 says

> Connotation is considered to be part of pragmatics.

What other parts does pragmatics have, besides connotation? (I can't think of none, but I don't really know anything.)

Thanks.

Comment: Wikipedia lists quite a few more things. Information Structure is one of the most important.

Answer (score 2):

Pragmatics is concerned with the meaning of utterances in context, that is, wrt common knowledge and previous discourse. One example would be the resolution of anaphors and, more interestingly, figurative speech such as idioms (e.g. “kick the bucket”). It’s also concerned with the coherence of discourse, mainly topic-focus articulation.